# Databricks 'schemaEvolutionMode' and 'schemaLocation' does not work together

Tags: schema, databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-autoloader

I am reading data from a parquet file, where new columns might get added so want use schema evolution with my existing schema.

The below code does not work

```
spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles')
            .option('cloudFiles.format', 'parquet')
            .option('cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true')
            .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', schema_path)
            .option('cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode', 'addNewColumns')
            .load(input_path))
```

But these two code work fine:

```
spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles')
            .option('cloudFiles.format', 'parquet')
            .option('cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true')
            .option('cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode', 'addNewColumns')
            .load(input_path))
```

```
spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles')
            .option('cloudFiles.format', 'parquet')
            .option('cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true')
            .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', schema_path)
            .load(input_path))
```

Comment: Which problem arises if you set both columns?

Comment: @RobertKossendey It does not identify newly added columns, any idea how to overwrite schema: pyspark.errors.exceptions.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `PROCESS_CODE` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following?

Comment: I currently have similar problems, maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482302/databricks-autoloader-schema-evolution-throws-stateschemanotcompatible-exception/77501039?noredirect=1#comment136631203_77501039